# Is it Possible to nest FormGroups inside each other in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I want to define a Form which consists of FormControls and FormGroups.

But i receive the following Error if i add the optionalInputGroup:

> TypeError: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function
>       at FormGroupDirective._updateDomValue (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:30206:19)
>       at FormGroupDirective.ngOnChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:30065:18)
>       at Wrapper_FormGroupDirective.ngDoCheck (/ReactiveFormsModule/FormGroupDirective/wrapper.ngfactory.js:30:18)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_ConfiguratorOptionalGroupInputComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/ConfiguratorOptionalGroupInputComponent/component.ngfactory.js:397:32)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:134498:14)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:134693:44)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:134483:18)
>       at View_ConfiguratorPage5.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/ConfiguratorPage/component.ngfactory.js:245:19)
>       at View_ConfiguratorPage5.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:134498:14)
>       at View_ConfiguratorPage5.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:134693:44)
>       at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:134830:37)
>       at View_ConfiguratorPage1.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/ConfiguratorPage/component.ngfactory.js:369:14)
>       at View_ConfiguratorPage1.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:134498:14)
>       at View_ConfiguratorPage1.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:134693:44)
>       at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:134830:37)

I create my FormConfig with the following Method:

```
flattenConfigForForm(inputs: [AbstractConfiguratorControl], returnObject = {}): Object {
  inputs.map(input => {
    switch (input.type) {
      case ConfigurationInputType.Group:
        let groupInput: ConfiguratorInputGroup = <ConfiguratorInputGroup> input;
        returnObject[groupInput.key] = groupInput;
        break;
      default:
        let basicInput: ConfiguratorInput = <ConfiguratorInput> input;
        returnObject[basicInput.key] = basicInput;
        returnObject[basicInput.key + ".ion"] = basicInput.value;
    }
  });
  return returnObject;
}
```

where ConfigurationInputType.Group is an instance of FormGroup with an `inputs`-Attribute which itself contains FormControls and `default` is an instance of FormControl.

This is how i build my form in html, where values is the FormGroup which was created by flattenConfigForForm.

```
  <form [formGroup]="values" (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
    <div class="requiredInputs">
      <div *ngFor="let input of config.inputs">
        <configurator-number-input [passedFormGroup]="values" *ngIf="isEqualType(input.type,configInputType.Number)"
                                   formControlName="{{input.key}}"></configurator-number-input>
        <configurator-toggle-input [passedFormGroup]="values" *ngIf="isEqualType(input.type,configInputType.Toggle)"
                                   formControlName="{{input.key}}"></configurator-toggle-input>
        <configurator-select-input [passedFormGroup]="values" *ngIf="isEqualType(input.type,configInputType.Select)"
                                   formControlName="{{input.key}}"></configurator-select-input>

        <configurator-optional-group-input formGroupName="{{input.key}}" [passedFormGroup]="input"
                                           formControlName="{{input.key}}"
                                           *ngIf="isEqualType(input.type,configInputType.Group)"></configurator-optional-group-input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

this is my formGroupInputComponent.html

```
<div [formGroup]="passedFormGroup">
  <ion-input>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="input.enabled"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-input>
  <div *ngFor="let subinput of input.inputs">
    <configurator-number-input [passedFormGroup]="input" *ngIf="isEqualType(subinput.type,configInputType.Number)"
                           formControlName="{{subinput.key}}"></configurator-number-input>
    <configurator-toggle-input [passedFormGroup]="input" *ngIf="isEqualType(subinput.type,configInputType.Toggle)"
                           formControlName="{{subinput.key}}"></configurator-toggle-input>
   <configurator-select-input [passedFormGroup]="input" *ngIf="isEqualType(subinput.type,configInputType.Select)"
                           formControlName="{{subinput.key}}"></configurator-select-input>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my formGroupInput.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'configurator-optional-group-input',
  templateUrl: 'configurator-optional-group-input.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ConfiguratorOptionalGroupInputComponent),
      multi: true,
    }
  ]
})
export class ConfiguratorOptionalGroupInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  input: ConfiguratorInputGroup;
  @Input() public passedFormGroup: FormGroup;
  // the method set in registerOnChange, it is just
  // a placeholder for a method that takes one parameter,
  // we use it to emit changes back to the form
  private propagateChange = (_: any) => {
  };

  constructor() {
  }

  //ControlValueAccessor
  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    if (obj) {
      console.log(this.passedFormGroup);
      this.input = <ConfiguratorInputGroup> obj;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  // not used, used for touch input
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you create a minimal working example in plunker?

Comment: `input` does not look like a `FormGroup` to me here: `[passedFormGroup]="input"`.

Comment: input is an instance of FormGroup because of the ngIf:*ngIf="isEqualType(input.type,configInputType.Group)".

Comment: Looks more like a instance of `ConfiguratorInputGroup`.

Comment: I don't see the point in implementing `ControlValueAccessor`, **and** passing a `FormGroup` as `@Input()`. I think you should separate the two things.